# Use Java to iterate between given placeholders in Excel

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-boot, apache-poi

Here is an example of what i could like to do:
[image: Excel Image]

Is there a way to output all the cells between startprint and end_print, i've got like 3 sheet in excel with same place holder, and i want to view only the data between startprint and endprint, for now all i can do is print out all the 3 sheet with all the content, here is my code:

```java
public class ReadInvoices {
    
    private static final String NAME = "C:\\Users\\........\\excelfile.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(NAME));
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
            Iterator<Sheet> sheets = workbook.sheetIterator();
            while(sheets.hasNext()) {
                Sheet sh = sheets.next();
                System.out.println("Sheet name is "+sh.getSheetName());
                System.out.println("---------");
                Iterator<Row> iterator = sh.iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row row = iterator.next();
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.iterator();
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                        String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);

                        System.out.print(cellValue+"\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            workbook.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What do the "OK" values in the cells signify?  Is there a meaning to the missing "OK" in cell 27h?

Comment: The Ok does not mean anything, i just want to print all the cell between the placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a spreadsheet to test this code.

The `processLines` method tests for the start print row and the end print row.  When we're in between the start print and end print rows, we print the rows.

I'm not sure if this line is correct.  I'm trying to get the cell from column A.

```
String text = row.getColumnObject(0);
```

Edit: Maybe this will work.

```
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.iterator();
Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
String text = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
```

Here's the example code.

```
public class ReadInvoices {

    private static final String NAME = "C:\\Users\\.......\excelfilename.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(NAME));
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
            Iterator<Sheet> sheets = workbook.sheetIterator();
            while (sheets.hasNext()) {
                Sheet sh = sheets.next();
                System.out.println("Sheet name is " + sh.getSheetName());
                System.out.println("---------");
                processLines(dataFormatter, sh);
            }
            workbook.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void processLines(DataFormatter dataFormatter, Sheet sh) {
        boolean printLine = false;
        Iterator<Row> iterator = sh.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = iterator.next();
            
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.iterator();
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            String text = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);

            if (printLine && text.equals("End_print")) {
                printLine = false;
            }
            
            if (printLine) {
                printRow(dataFormatter, row);
            } 
            
            if (!printLine && text.equals("StartPrint")) {
                printLine = true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static void printRow(DataFormatter dataFormatter, Row row) {
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.iterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);

            System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.. but that getColumnObject(0); is giving me error, i've been searching how to resole it. if you know any way, please let me know, thanks again.

Comment: here is the excel file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=04317181325866273878

Comment: Do you know why it's not working with this excel file? http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=85991379923585377185

Comment: it's giving me this error: java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1209)